# How to make 2 columns without using multicols environment?

Tags: two-column

I want to write 3 lines in the middle of my paper in 2 columns, but I don't want to use `multicols` environment. I want to start each line and write in the second column with a specific distance from the beginning of the line. for example:

```
(beginning of the first line)Hello People          (beginning at the 10cm distance from the beginning of the line)Hello People

(beginning of the second line)Hello People          (beginning at the 10cm distance from the beginning of the line)Hello People

(beginning of the third line)Hello People          (beginning at the 10cm distance from the beginning of the line)Hello People
```

I used `\hspace` but the problem is the `\hspace` will fix the distance from the end of the line based on the end of the second column words not the beginning of the second column words.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but did you try using two `minipages` next two each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? (It employs two side-by-side `minipage` environments, and the width of the first `minipage` is set to `10cm`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\mylength % width of second minipage calculated as a residual
\setlength\mylength\textwidth
\addtolength\mylength{-10cm}

\begin{document}
\hrule\smallskip % just to illustrate width of textblock

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
\raggedright
Hello People.

Hello People.

Hello People.
\end{minipage}% no space
\begin{minipage}[t]{\mylength}
\raggedright
Hello People.

Hello People.

Hello People.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Zarko - I think the left-hand column in your (currently deleted) `tabularx`-based answer should have been defined as `p{\dimexpr10cm-2\tabcolsep}`.